# CodePipeline failing with "The action failed because either the artifact or the Amazon S3 bucket could not be found."

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline

I have the following pipeline definition:

```
  Pipeline:
    Type: 'AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline'
    Properties:
       Name: !Ref AppName
       RoleArn: {"Fn::GetAtt" : ["PipelineServiceRole", "Arn"] }
       ArtifactStore:
          Type: S3
          Location: !Ref ArtifactBucket
       Stages: 
        - 
          Name: Source
          Actions: 
            - 
              Name: SourceAction
              ActionTypeId: 
                Category: Source
                Owner: AWS
                Version: 1
                Provider: S3
              OutputArtifacts: 
                - Name: "PipelineArtifact"
              Configuration: 
                S3Bucket: !Ref ArtifactBucket
                S3ObjectKey: !Ref ArtifactName
                PollForSourceChanges: true
              RunOrder: 1
        - 
          Name: Deploy
          Actions: 
            - 
              Name: DeployAction
              ActionTypeId: 
                Category: Deploy
                Owner: AWS
                Version: 1
                Provider: ElasticBeanstalk
              InputArtifacts: 
                - Name: "PipelineArtifact"
              Configuration:
                ApplicationName: !Ref EbApplication
                EnvironmentName: !Ref EbEnvironment
```

The source stage completes successfully but then I get this error in the Deploy stage:

[image: Error Message]

I already checked that the artifact is at the expected location in S3 and the PipelineServiceRole has full permissions (literally `*/*`).

What could be causing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `Provider: ElasticBeanstalk`, the `S3ObjectKey` MUST point to a `.zip` file.

(and no, a `.jar` won't work)